# Why does my class cost so much memory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory

```
from guppy import hpy

hp = hpy()


class Demo(object):
    __slots__ = ('v0', 'v1')

    def __init__(self, v0, v1):
        self.v0 = v0
        self.v1 = v1


from array import array

value = 1.01
ar = array('f')
ar2 = array('f')
for i in range(5000000):
    ar.append(value + i)
    ar2.append(value + i * 0.1 + i * 0.01 + i * 0.001 + i * 0.0001 + i * 0.000001)
a = []
for i in range(5000000):
    vex = Demo(ar[i], ar[2])
    a.append(vex)
print "Heap at the end of the functionn", hp.heap()
```

Here is the output:

```
Heap at the end of the functionn Partition of a set of 15063247 objects. Total       size = 650251664 bytes.

Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
0 5000000  33 320000000  49 320000000  49 __main__.Demo
1 10000108  66 240002592  37 560002592  86 float
2    368   0 42008896   6 602011488  93 list
3      2   0 40000112   6 642011600  99 array.array
4  28182   0  2214784   0 644226384  99 str
5  12741   0  1058448   0 645284832  99 tuple
6    189   0   669624   0 645954456  99 dict of module
7    371   0   588104   0 646542560  99 dict (no owner)
8    258   0   509232   0 647051792 100 dict of sip.wrappertype
9   3176   0   406528   0 647458320 100 types.CodeType
```

I am wondering why the Demo class cost so much memory. Because Demo class just keeps a reference for the float, it doesn't copy the float value.

```
getSizeOf(Demo) # 984
```

50W of Demo class maybe just cost memory: `984*50W=40215176` but, now costs `320000000`.
It is unbelievable, why?

Comment: 984 times 50 million is 4920000000, not 40215176.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.getsizeof()` doesn't recurse into sub-objects, and you only took the size of the *class*, not of an instance. Each instance takes up 64 bytes, plus 24 bytes per `float` object (on OS X, using Python 2.7.12):

```
>>> d = Demo(1.0, 2.0)
>>> sys.getsizeof(d)
64
>>> sys.getsizeof(d.v0)
24
>>> sys.getsizeof(d) + sys.getsizeof(d.v0) + sys.getsizeof(d.v1)
112
```

Each slot only reserves memory for a *pointer* in the instance object; on my machine that's 8 bytes per pointer.

There are *several* differences between your `Demo()` instances and the array:

- Instances have a minimal overhead to support reference counting and weak references, as well as contain a pointer to their class. The arrays store the values directly, without any of that overhead.
- The instance stores *Python* floats. These are full-fledged objects, including reference counting and weak reference support. The array stores **single precision** floats as C values, while the Python `float` object models **double** precision floats. So the instance uses 2 * 24 bytes (on my Mac) just for those floats, vs. just 4 bytes per single-precision `'f'` value in an array.
- To track 5 million `Demo` instances, you also needed to create a `list` object, which is sized to handle *at least* 5 million object references. The `array` stores the C single-precision floats directly.

The `hp.heap()` output only counts the instance footprint, not the referenced `float` values on each line, but the totals match up:

- 5 million times 64 bytes is 320.000.000 bytes of memory for the `Demo` instances.
- 10 million times 24 bytes is 240.000.000 bytes of memory for the `float` instances, plus a further 108 floats referenced elsewhere.

Together, these two groups make up the majority of the 15 million Python objects on the heap.

- The `list` object you created to hold the instances contains 5 million pointers, that's 40.000.000 bytes just to point to all the `Demo` instances, plus the accounting overhead for that object. There are a further 367 lists on the heap, referenced by other Python code.
- 2 `array` instances with each 5 million 4-byte floats is 40.000.000 bytes, plus 56 bytes per array overhead.

So `array` objects are *vastly more efficient* to store a large number of numeric values, because it stores these as primitive C values. However, the disadvantage is that Python has to *box* each value you try to access; so accessing `ar[10]` returns a Python `float` object.